# Unable to merge 2 mp4 files using media extractor and media muxer

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am trying to merge multiple video files (mp4) into one file. I tried using mp4 parser, but unable to get required result for that as well. (Going to post issue later on their github)

I tried following code.

getVideoFile(int i) just returns absolute path of video number i. (sample1.mp4, sample2.mp4 like that).

After running this code, I end up getting mp4 with size equivalent to addition of sizes of all videos. That means all frames are added to final mp4. Audio is perfectly combined and I am able to hear it fine.

Only problem is video. Frames are somehow getting misplaced due to invalid presentationTime I guess. Frames are randomly displayed on video.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    val muxer: MediaMuxer = MediaMuxer(getOutputPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
    var tracksAdded = 0
    var muxerStarted = false
    val indexMap = HashMap<Int, Int>()

    for(i in 2 until 6){
        val extractor = MediaExtractor()
        extractor.setDataSource(getVideoFile(i))
        val trackCount = extractor.trackCount
        //assertEquals("wrong number of tracks", expectedTrackCount, trackCount)
        // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.

        // Set up the tracks.
        for (i in 0 until trackCount) {
            val format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i)
                if (tracksAdded != 2) {
                    val dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(format)
                    indexMap[i] = dstIndex
                    tracksAdded++
                }
        }

        if(!muxerStarted) {
            muxer.start()
            muxerStarted = true
        }

        // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer.
        var sawEOS = false
        val bufferSize = MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE
        var frameCount = 0
        val offset = 100
        val dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize)
        val bufferInfo = BufferInfo()

        while (!sawEOS) {
            bufferInfo.offset = offset
            bufferInfo.size = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset)

            if (bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG !== 0){
                bufferInfo.size = 0
            }

            if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                Timber.d("newCombine saw eos")
                sawEOS = true
                bufferInfo.size = 0
            } else {
                bufferInfo.flags = extractor.sampleFlags
                val trackIndex = extractor.sampleTrackIndex

                if(extractor.sampleTime< prevOutputPTSUs) {
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = prevOutputPTSUs + 300
                }else{
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractor.sampleTime
                }
                muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap[trackIndex] ?: 0, dstBuf,
                        bufferInfo)
                prevOutputPTSUs = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs
                extractor.advance()
                frameCount++
                Log.d("newCombine", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") " +
                        "PresentationTimeUs:" + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +
                        " Flags:" + bufferInfo.flags +
                        " TrackIndex:" + trackIndex +
                        " Size(KB) " + bufferInfo.size / 1024)
            }
        }
    }

    muxer.stop()
    muxer.release()
```

I know, approach I am using for presentation time might be completely wrong, but audio is properly getting merged but not video.